# Excel - sum first values found based on another column

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, sum, row

in the table below, I have in column A a reference number and in column B a value that is null or positive:

| Reference | Volume |
| --- | --- |
| 074610 | 100 |
| 074610 | 0 |
| 171546 | 0 |
| 171546 | 200 |
| 751714 | 0 |
| 751714 | 50 |
| 751714 | 0 |
| 789723 | 25 |

Outside of the table, I would like to sum column B only on the values that matches the first row with a different reference. In my example, it would mean that I only add

- the first row for reference 074610,
- the first row for reference 171546,
- the first row for reference 751747,
- etc.

The formula should give a result: 100 + 0 + 0 + 25 = 125 but all the formulas I tried give the total of column without taking into account the first row for each reference number.

Does anyone has an idea of fomula that could work?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B9*(A2:A9<>A1:A8))
```

[image]

Comment: Hello this works perfeclty, but do you have a way to take the formula more dynamic if I had row below the table?